# Getting the longest string using properties

Tags: c#

I have following code:

```
public string Longest
{
    get
    {
        int min = int.MinValue;
        string longest = "";
        for (Node i = Head; i != null; i = i.Next)
        {
            if (i.Text.Length > min)
            {
                longest = i.Text.Length.ToString();
            }

            return longest;
        }

        return longest;
    }
}
```

The problem is I have those strings:

```
List text = new List();
text.Add("Petar");
text.Add("AHS");
text.Add("Google");
text.Add("Me");
```

When I try out the propertie it says that the longest string is 5 but thats not true the longest string is six. I've tried to find out where my problem but i coulnd't find it.

Comment: The first `return longest;` will return on the first iteration of the loop, you don't need that one

Comment: Are you restricted in how you can find the longest string?  Because your way is not really the easiest.  Besides that, @CamiloTerevinto gave you the right answer

Comment: Yes im searching the longest string

Comment: @maccettura Not the easiest, not the most common... seeing the deprecated non-generic List version being used makes this look like homework

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto good eye, did not even notice it was non-generic.   I also just realized all of this is happening in a property.  Weird

Comment: Yes we are learning how the lists actually works. But i can't find out where did I made mistake.

Comment: @GeorgeMan the very first comment tells you what your mistake is

Comment: The smallest it can be is 0, so `int min = -1;` would suffice.

Comment: I added as u said but afterthat the string is 2

Comment: @GeorgeMan what did you add?  We told you to **remove** something

Comment: You initialise min but you do not update it after finding a longer string - so now it is return the last length. You need to add _"min = i.Text.Length;"_ You don't really need to set longest - you can _"return min.ToString;"_ if you really need the length as a string.

Comment: I removed the return from the loop and changed int.MinValue to min - 1

Comment: @maccettura: OP is not returning _"min"_ (just comparing against it) - but _"longest"_ - but see my updated comment.

Comment: @PaulF yeah I realized your intent after commenting.

Comment: You don't even need `min`. Your logic should be something like "compare current text length to *longest* and if it is longer, then set longest to that length instead". After you've looped through all your text then `longest` will contain the length of the longest string.

Comment: I wanted to have a min and after that to say if is it longer that thats the longest string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a couple of problems:

- A length can be, as minimum, 0, so you don't need to use `int.MinValue`
- You are returning on the first iteration
- You are not updating `min` after finding a longer value
- You are returning the length of the string, not the string itself

Your code should look like this:

```
public string Longest
{
    get
    {
        int longestLength = 0;
        string longestWord = string.Empty;

        for (Node i = Head; i != null; i = i.Next)
        {
            if (i.Text.Length > longestLength)
            {
                longestLength = i.Text.Length;
                longestWord = i.Text;
            }
        }

        return longestWord;
    }
}
```

If what you want to return is the *maximum length* instead of the word with the maximum length, your property is both wrongly named and typed, and it should look like this instead:

```
public int MaximumLength
{
    get
    {
        int maximumLength = 0;

        for (Node i = Head; i != null; i = i.Next)
        {
            if (i.Text.Length > maximumLength)
            {
                maximumLength  = i.Text.Length;
            }
        }

        return maximumLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much very helpful explanion.

Comment: @GeorgeMan Glad to help, you may want to read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `IEnumerable<string>` then do the following

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("AAA");
list.Add("AAAAA");
list.Add("A");
list.Add("AAAA");
list.Add("AAAAAA");
list.Add("AA");

// max has the longest string
var max = list.Aggregate(string.Empty, 
          (bookmark, item) => item.Length>bookmark.Length ? item : bookmark);
```

or using a loop

```
string max = string.Empty;
int length=0;
foreach(var item in list)
{
    if(item.Length>length)
    {
        max = item;
        length = item.Length;
    }
}
```

But it appears you have a linked list which I recreated as a skeleton below:

```
public class Node 
{
    public Node(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        this.Head = this;
    }
    public Node(Node parent, string text): this(text)
    {
        if(parent!=null)
        {
            parent.Next = this;
            this.Head = parent.Head;
        }
    }
    public Node Head { get; }
    public Node Next { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; }
    public Node Add(string text) => new Node(this, text);
}
```

and finding the longest string with a loop is

```
var list = new Node("AAA");
list = list.Add("AAAAA");
list = list.Add("A");
list = list.Add("AAAA");
list = list.Add("AAAAAA");
list = list.Add("AA");


string max = list.Text;
int length = max.Length;
for(Node node = list.Head; node != null; node = node.Next)
{
    if(node.Text.Length > length)
    {
        max = node.Text;
        length= node.Text.Length;
    }
}

// max has the longest string
```

**Edit 1**

I took the linked list and made it `IEnumerable<string>` by moving your loop code into a method:

```
public class Node : IEnumerable<string>
{
    public Node(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        this.Head = this;
    }
    public Node(Node parent, string text) : this(text)
    {
        if(parent!=null)
        {
            parent.Next = this;
            this.Head = parent.Head;
        }
    }
    public Node Head { get; }
    public Node Next { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; }
    public Node Add(string text) => new Node(this, text);

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Loop through the list, starting from head to end
        for(Node node = Head; node != null; node = node.Next)
        {
            yield return node.Text;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator(); 
}
```

and now I can use a single `LINQ` statement

```
var list = new Node("AAA");
list = list.Add("AAAAA");
list = list.Add("A");
list = list.Add("AAAA");
list = list.Add("AAAAAA");
list = list.Add("AA");


// max has the longest string
var max = list.Aggregate(string.Empty, 
          (bookmark, item) => item.Length>bookmark.Length ? item : bookmark);
```